# Listen for socket.io in an Angular App

Tags: javascript, angularjs, socket.io

I'm looking to integrate socket.io with my angular app. I've seen some examples of how to create a service, which makes it accessible on the controller. Which I understand. But I'm looking for a way that all the controllers can react to event calls from socket.io.

So:

> socket.on('user joined', function (data) {});

I can do that in one controller but how do I do it for all?

Comment: You should do it in a service and inject it into a controller.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll want to [encapsulate your socket in a service and inject it into Angular controllers as needed](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/frameworks/angular-websockets/).

Let's make a socket service:

```
app.factory('socket', function ($rootScope) {
  var socket = io.connect();
  return {
    on: function (eventName, callback) {
      socket.on(eventName, function () {  
        var args = arguments;
        $rootScope.$apply(function () {
          callback.apply(socket, args);
        });
      });
    },
    emit: function (eventName, data, callback) {
      socket.emit(eventName, data, function () {
        var args = arguments;
        $rootScope.$apply(function () {
          if (callback) {
            callback.apply(socket, args);
          }
        });
      })
    }
  };
});
```

Then we'll inject into a controller and interact with it (through the `socket.io` API):

```
function AppCtrl($scope, socket) {
  socket.on('init', function (data) {
    $scope.name = data.name;
    $scope.users = data.users;
  });
}
```

You can obviously customize the controller to do what you need to with the socket service.

Comment: Yes, I realize that is no point having it in all controllers... Obviously! My question now is how to initialise the connection "var socket = io.connect();" will it start a new connection every time I instantiate it?

Comment: got it! But now I'm having trouble with, "Uncaught ReferenceError: io is not defined"

Comment: Do you have the `socket.io` js referenced on your client page? You might have to [start the listener on the server](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13372692/4118286) too.