# Socket.io.js can't be found (404)

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

I've developed a small chat application with Socket.io and Express, currently deployed on my droplet at digital ocean. You can see it live at https://keleheart.com/chatapp. It currently doesn't work because the server is giving back a 404 for the chatapp/socket.io/socket.io.js script I have at the bottom of my html file, should be able to see that when you visit the site and hit f12

I've been through a few fixes already that were popular on here such as [This one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10191048/socket-io-js-not-found) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25525177/socket-io-js-not-found-node-js-express-socket-io) and I've even tried changing the script from local to a CDN as depicted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5636461/socket-io-io-is-not-defined-js-error) , and the CDN seems to work better,(still gives the 404 but it then no longer says io isn't defined??) but it still doesn't produce the output I need.

You are able to review my repo on my [Github Page](https://github.com/Yintii/Small-Chat-app) for this as well, there's just the index.html file for the client and then the chatApp.js for the server. The error is coming from my html file but all the fixes have told me to manipulate my package.json, server variables, and nothing has worked so far. My server still cannot find chatapp/socket.io/socket.io.js

[image]

Comment: I don't see your server code in your repo. Since you're using a reverse proxy that adds an additional prefix (`/chatapp`), I guess that the location of the `socket.io.js` file should also get that prefix: `src='/chatapp/socket.io/socket.io.js'` (although that would probably require setting the `path` option to `io()`). Or, possibly, use a relative path (`src='socket.io/socket.io.js`).

Comment: @robertklep - Weird, I saw what you said to be true, not sure what happened to it but I recommited and it's in there again now. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried creating the `/socket.io` folder next to `index.html`, and putting a copy of socket.io.js inside of that? That has always worked for me, but you might have to hunt through the `node_modules` folder to get the file. This always fixed it for me.

And of course, be sure to actually serve the file using express's static method.

Your browser is giving you the correct error message. Since `/socket.io/socket.io.js` does not exist on the server, the browser displays the server's 404 message.

Comment: Since I'm using a reverse proxy to serve more than one app, this app is resolving at domain.com/chatapp, and my script in not looking along this path it seems. I've found the socket.io.js file and it's in a folder next to the index file, but I now can't figure out how to server the static files of a second app on the server.